# MongoDB Driver with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, php-mongodb

I'm trying to do a module with Zend Framework 2, Doctrine and Mongodb but i'm in front of a little problem.

I realized that the mongoDB driver was not installed.

MongoDB is installed; I have the service running. I already have the mongodb driver, `mongo.so` and it's installed in the PHP extension directory.

I added the `extension=mongo.so` line in the `php.ini` (the `/cli/php.ini` and the `/apache2/php.ini`)

I have an error:

> Class 'mongo' not found

When I look at the output of `phpinfo()`; Mongo is not installed.

What is missing ?

**Edit:** The output of `phpinfo()` in de public folder of zend show that mongodb is installed, but the output of  `phpinfo()` in the module of zend show nothing about mongo.

**Edit:** With the command `php -m`, the section `[Zend Module]` is empty ...

Comment: After you edited php.ini have you restarted server?

Comment: I restarted Apache2 with sudo service apache2 restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

I just had to reboot Zend Framework

With `php -s adress:port -t */ZendSkeletonAplication/public/ */www/zframework/public/index.php &` (with `extension=mongo.so` in the `/cli/php.ini` )

This command works for me, please adapt with your path and it should work for you as well.

So don't forget to do that if you have the same issue!